# Getting CPU time error

Tags: apex, governorlimits, performance, cpulimit

I tried to make use of maps but still getting CPU time error.

**Code:**

```
 //@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, Integer> getDateRangeMap()
{
    Map<String, Integer> mapToReturn = new Map<String, Integer>();
    Integer mnth = System.Today().MOnth();
    Integer yr = System.Today().Year();
    Integer previousmonth = Date.today().addMonths(-1).month();
     Integer nextmonth = Date.today().addMonths(1).month();
            List<customobj__c> myCalls = new List<customobj__c>([SELECT Id,  Name, Date__c FROM customobj__c where owner.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() and CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c)= :yr and (CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c)= :previousmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c)= :nextmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c)= :mnth ]);
   .
    List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>([select Id, Name, closeDate from Opportunity where closeDate != NULL AND StageName!= 'Won - Closed' AND StageName!= 'Closed - No Win' AND ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserId()and CALENDAR_MONTH(closeDate)= :mnth and CALENDAR_YEAR(closeDate)= :yr]); 
    List<Event> lstEvent = new List<Event>([SELECT AccountId,EndDateTime,Id,StartDateTime,Subject FROM Event  where ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() and CALENDAR_MONTH(StartDateTime)= :mnth and CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDateTime)= :yr]);

    //processing the data for the map. 
    //Logic - Iterate through all dates{Iterate over list--Transform the date with the string--iterate for its count}
    for(customobj__c objCR : myCalls){
        mapToReturn.put(objCR.Date__c.format(), 0);
        //system.debug('mapToReturn CR'+mapToReturn);
    }

    for(Opportunity oOpp : lstOpp){
        mapToReturn.put(oOpp.closeDate.format() , 0);
         system.debug('mapToReturn opp'+mapToReturn);
    }

    for(Event oEvt : lstEvent)
    {
        if(oEvt.StartDateTime != NULL)
        {
            mapToReturn.put(oEvt.StartDateTime.date().format() , 0);  
             system.debug('mapToReturn Evt SD'+mapToReturn);
        }
        if(oEvt.EndDateTime != NULL)
        {
            mapToReturn.put(oEvt.EndDateTime.date().format() , 0);
             system.debug('mapToReturn Evt ED'+mapToReturn);
        }

        //we got all unique dates now. Now, we'll iterate through all the obj loops to get count
        for(String oStr : mapToReturn.keySet())
        {
            //convert string into date again.
            system.debug('oStr'+oStr);
            Date d = Date.parse(oStr);
            Integer count = mapToReturn.get(oStr);
            system.debug('!!!!!count'+count);
            for(customobj__c objCR : myCalls)
            {
                if(objCR.Date__c != NULL ){
                    if( d.isSameDay(objCR.Date__c) ){
                        count = count + 1;
                    }    
                }
            }

            for(Opportunity oOpp : lstOpp){
                if(oOpp.CloseDate != NULL ){
                    if(d.isSameDay(oOpp.CloseDate) ){
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(Event oEvtt : lstEvent){
                if(oEvtt.StartDateTime != NULL){

                    if(oEvtt.EndDateTime == NULL){
                        if( d.isSameDay(oEvtt.StartDateTime.date())){
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(oEvtt.StartDateTime.date().daysBetween(d) >=0 && oEvtt.EndDateTime.date().daysBetween(d) <= 0 ){
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

          mapToReturn.put(oStr, count);


        }

    }
    System.debug(mapToReturn);
    return mapToReturn;
}
```

**Here is the updated logic:**

```
 Map<Date, Integer> myMap = new Map<Date, Integer>();  
  Integer mnth = System.Today().MOnth();
  Integer yr = System.Today().Year();
  Integer previousmonth = Date.today().addMonths(-1).month();
  Integer nextmonth = Date.today().addMonths(1).month();

  for(AggregateResult aggregate3:[SELECT day_only(StartDateTime), count(Id) records1   FROM Event WHERE owner.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() and CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDateTime)= :yr and (CALENDAR_MONTH(StartDateTime)= :previousmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(StartDateTime)= :nextmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(StartDateTime)= :mnth )  GROUP BY day_only(StartDateTime)]){
    Date key = (Date)aggregate3.get('expr0');
    Integer value = (Integer)aggregate3.get('records1');
    myMap.put(key,value);
 }

    for(AggregateResult aggregate :[SELECT Date__c, count(Id) records  FROM myobject__c WHERE owner.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() and CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c)= :yr and (CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c)= :previousmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c)= :nextmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c)= :mnth )  GROUP BY Date__c]){
 Date key = (Date)aggregate.get('Date__c');
 Integer value = (Integer)aggregate.get('records');
 myMap.get(key) += value;
}

for(AggregateResult aggregate2:[SELECT closeDate, count(Id)  FROM Opportunity WHERE owner.Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() and CALENDAR_YEAR(closeDate)= :yr and (CALENDAR_MONTH(closeDate)= :previousmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(closeDate)= :nextmonth or CALENDAR_MONTH(closeDate)= :mnth )  GROUP BY closeDate]){
 Date key = (Date)aggregate2.get('closeDate');
 Integer value = (Integer)aggregate2.get('expr0');
 myMap.get(key) += value;

}
```

Comment: Consider moving this to javascript if you're getting CPU errors. Use the controller to return the record lists back to the component and let the component handle the rest.

Comment: Please note that creating duplicate accounts to circumvent a question ban is likely to get you into further trouble. I suggest you request to merge your account with [this likely duplicate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/44477) rather than getting caught and further punished.

Comment: debug statements consume cpu time

Answer (score 2):

You're doing several things which are inefficient:

- Don't instantiate a new list with query results. **A query already returns a list.**

  Instead of:

  ```
  List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject__c>([/*query*/]);
  ```

  Just use:

  ```
  List<MyObject__c> records = [/*query*/];
  ```
- Casting from date to string and then back to date is just wasting time. You get the date values from your records, then save the value as a string, but when you retrieve it you actually need the date. Save yourself the data-type-roundtrip.

  Instead of:

  ```
  Map<String, Integer> myMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
  // ...
  myMap.put(someDate.format(), 0);
  // ...
  for (String key : myMap.keySet())
  {
      Date dateKey = Date.parse(key);
      // converting back and forth like this is inefficient
  }
  ```

  Use:

  ```
  Map<Date, Integer> myMap = new Map<Date, Integer>();
  // ...
  myMap.put(someDate, 0);
  // ...
  for (Date dateKey : myMap.keySet())
  {
      // now you already have the date value
  }
  ```
- Aggregate queries can do a lot of the computing for you without counting against CPU Time. Something like:

  ```
  for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
      SELECT MyDateField__c, count(Id) records
      FROM MyObject
      WHERE ...
      GROUP BY MyDateField__c
  ]){
      Date key = (Date)aggregate.get('MyDateField__c');
      Integer value = (Integer)aggregate.get('records');
      myMap.get(key) += value;
  }
  ```
- You don't need `daysBetween` to do comparison, nor to even to get the `Date` instance from the `Datetime`.

  Instead of:

  ```
  if (startDatetime.date().daysBetween(myDate) >= 0 && endDatetime.date().daysBetween(myDate) <= 0)
  ```

  Just use:

  ```
  if (startDatetime <= myDate && endDatetime >= myDate)
  ```

As noted in the comments:

- Remove all your debug statements. They consume CPU Time.
- Make sure you are not logging at a too-fine level of granularity either. In fact, if your user has a trace flag, set all debug levels to the lowest value.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated my logic by using aggregated result but when I am trying to assign integer value to the map by getting the key, I am hitting error saying 'Expression cannot be assigned' when using  myMap.get(key) += value; Anyway we could add the count value to the Map value of specific key?

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried...